# Write log messages to Grafana Loki via Fluentd

Tags: c#, grafana, serilog, fluentd, grafana-loki

We have .NET WebAPI services (C#) that use Serilog for logging application trace messages.  We use only one Serilog sink, TCPSink, to squirt out messages to Fluentd sidecar containers so we can easily change the logging destination without having to change the WebAPI application code.  This has worked well for targets such as Elasticsearch and Humio.  We would now like to support Grafana Loki with a new Fluentd sidecar container.

Using TCPSink with the default formatted (JsonFormatter), we can easily support the format for Elasticsearch/Humio (logstash?).  But the format for Loki is vastly different.  Is there way for format the messages in Fluentd from essentially raw JSON to the stream format as required by Grafana Loki?  Or should we write a 'LokiFormatter' and use it with TCPSink, similar to the GrafanaLoki sink?

Here is some test code in C#.  We wish to use the TCPSink sink.  Note that the commented-out 'GrafanaLoki' sink does work.

```
 private static void Main()
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
                .AddYamlFile(CONFIGURATION_FILE_NAME, optional: false)
                .Build();            
           
            try
            {
                loggingLevel.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;

                var lc = new LoggerConfiguration();

                lc.MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(loggingLevel);
                lc.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning);
                lc.MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error);

                Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => System.Console.WriteLine(msg));

                lc.WriteTo.Console();
                lc.WriteTo.TCPSink("tcp://localhost:9880");

                //var credentials = new LokiCredentials() { Login = "**username**", Password = "**password** };
                //lc.WriteTo.GrafanaLoki("https://logs-prod-us-central1.grafana.net", credentials: credentials);

                lc.Enrich.FromLogContext();
                lc.Enrich.WithProperty("applicationName", APPLICATION_NAME);
                lc.Enrich.WithProperty("environment", "dev");

                Log.Logger = lc.CreateLogger();

                int bob = 111;
                Log.Information("This is a test {bob}", bob);

                var msg = "Danger! Danger! Will Robinson!";
                Log.Warning("This is a warning : {msg}", msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, $"Error in {APPLICATION_NAME}");
            }
            finally
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the Dockerfile for a proposed Loki sidecar container.

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.14.0-1.0
# FROM __DockerBaseImage__
USER root
RUN fluent-gem install fluent-plugin-grafana-loki
COPY fluentd.conf /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
USER fluent
```

with configuration

```
<source>
  @type tcp
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse>
  port 9880
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag xxxx
</source>
<match xxxx>
  @type loki
  url                 https://logs-prod-us-central1.grafana.net
  username            **username**
  password            **password**
  extra_labels        {"env":"dev","farm":"a"} 
  flush_interval      5s
  flush_at_shutdown   true
  buffer_chunk_limit  1m
</match>
```

Is there a way to add a parser/filter in Fluentd to format the incoming TCP JSON for Loki?  Or a correct fluentd plugin instead of 'fluent-plugin-grafana-loki'?